# Convert SliderTextInput from taking a single value to multiple

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I'm building a shiny app and using a `SliderTextInput` for a time period selector. I'm adding another option to allow user to switch from viewing values at a point in time to change over a period. I want to use `updateSliderTextInput` to convert the year selector from accepting a single value to accepting a range, but updating the selected parameter doesn't do the trick (it just takes the first in the list of new values supplied to the selected argument). It even looks like the css of a range and single-value slider is the same so it doesn't seem like I can fix by updating the css either.

I have a work around, which is just creating two sliders and keeping one of them hidden at all times using shinyjs, but I'm curious as to whether I can use `updateSliderTextInput` in this way.
Thanks